# Trying to create a Blob Object for a (txt) file to insert into a database

Tags: java, grails, blob

I Am supposed to follow some of the following steps:
would be glad to know where i am going wrong
1 . create a Blob reference in domain class (represents the uploaded file

```
java.sql.Blob userfile;//blob reference
```

1. in controller creating an object of the blob using SerialBlob
   in controller.

   (fullref).userfile =new SerialBlob(         [ I don't know what to pass here ]   );
2. then i want to invoke  setBinaryStream method on the blob object and returned outputstream should be sent for saving in the db.

Please Help !! Thanking You all In advance.

Comment: For a text file, you need a Clob (Character Large Object), not a Blob (Binary Large Object).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `java.sql.Blob`, you could simply use a byte array.

The type of the mapped field is direved from your `maxSize` constraint.

```
class ExampleDomain {
    ...
    byte[] userfile

    static constraints = {
        ...
        userfile maxSize: 10000000
    }
}
```

The above example generates a field of type `mediumblob` in MySQL.

If you chosse a bigger `maxSize` constraint, other blob types will be used.

Now you could create an instance of `ExampleDomain` like this:

```
def example = new ExampleDomain(userfile: yourFile.bytes,....)
```